# Putting singles and lists into a list in clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a more elegant way to have `into` work with single items and lists than the following (admittedly atrocious) function?

```
(defn into-1-or-more
  [this-list list-or-single]
  (into this-list (flatten (conj [] list-or-single))))
```

Which can handle either:

```
(into-1-or-more [1 2 3 4] 5)
;[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Or:

```
(into-1-or-more [1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8])
;[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I am building a collection with reduce using `into []` with results from functions in a list. However some of the functions return single items, and others return lists of items. Like:

```
(reduce #(into [] (% data)) [func-return-item func-return-list func-return-either])
```

Would the best solution be to just do the following instead?

```
(into [] (flatten (map #(% data) [func-return-item ...])
```

Comment: I would avoid using `reduce` if not necessary, `reduce` is not lazy, `map` instead is.

Comment: In this particular case all data is consumed anyways. You are of course right though.

Comment: Also have a look at https://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/10/clojure-donts-heisenparameter

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm still mulling over what I think. It definitely brings up valid points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it would be more ideal to know for sure what return type you are getting, here is a simple answer:

```
(flatten [ curr-list (mystery-fn) ] )
```

Examples:

```
(flatten [[1 2 3] 9 ] )
;=> (1 2 3 9)
(flatten [[[1] 2 3] [4 5] 6 ] )
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

You could wrap it into a function if you want, but it hardly seems necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This transducer flattens sequential inputs, but only by one "level":

```
(defn maybe-cat [rf]
  (let [catrf (cat rf)]
    (fn
      ([] (rf))
      ([result] (rf result))
      ([result input]
       (if (sequential? input)
         (catrf result input)
         (rf result input))))))
```

Example:

```
(into [] maybe-cat [[:foo] :bar [[:quux]]])
;= [:foo :bar [:quux]]
```

As this example demonstrates, this approach makes it possible to include sequential collections in the output (by wrapping them in an additional sequential layer – `[[:quux]]` produces `[:quux]` in the output).